# Speaker Verification models on

Tags: deep-learning, classification, speaker-verfication

- I went through different articles of speaker verifications (`ECAPA-TDNN`, `TITANET`).
- They trained on `VoxCeleb` dataset.
- In this dataset (`voxceleb`) some speakers have many more files than other speakers (imbalanced classes).
- Those articles didn't mentioned how did they handle this imbalanced

Do we need to balanced the classes (number of files per speaker) ?